# Python: onkeypress without turtle window?

Tags: python, window, turtle-graphics

My problem at this time is, that I want to detect a keypress through the command

```
onkeypress(fun,"key")
```

but when I import  onkeypress and listen from turtle, a turtle window pops out, when I run my program. Do you know how to close it again, or how to not even let it appear?
Thanks for hopefully coming answers, sorry for my bad english (I'm german and 13)

Answer (score 0):

It might be hard to find experts in python [turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html). However, if you are not limited to that library, you may use the following code to get the key pressed by the user (last call actually gets the key for you):

```
class _Getch:
    """Gets a single character from standard input.  Does not echo to the
screen."""
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.impl = _GetchWindows()
        except ImportError:
            self.impl = _GetchUnix()

    def __call__(self): return self.impl()


class _GetchUnix:
    def __init__(self):
       import tty, sys

    def __call__(self):
        import sys, tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch


class _GetchWindows:
    def __init__(self):
        import msvcrt

    def __call__(self):
        import msvcrt
        return msvcrt.getch()


getch = _Getch()
```

Code comes from [this article](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/)